# Eclipse installation doesn't exist in Programs

Tags: eclipse, installation, ide

I downloaded and ran eclipse.exe.exe for installation, but it doesn't get added to the Programs as an Installed software. I always get to locate the .exe and launch the IDE from there. Any thoughts why it doesn't get installed as a Program?

Comment: Are you **certain** that's the file name you downloaded?

Comment: Yes. I am also able to launch the Eclipse using the executable (eclipse.exe file) and use the IDE, but I am curious why is it not installing as a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't work as a regular installation, but as an archive of related files, majorly because to create as much as a loose connection to the environment/OS as possible. Applications that are installed need to update data in OS registry and is therefore on some points restricted. In your Eclipse IDE you can specify own registries with data relevant for the project.

Another benefit is that it's easily updated and can also be easily shared between work stations without installation. That gives flexibility, if your workspace is corrupted, you don't need to uninstall, reinstall, restart and all that stuff. All you need is to take a back up of your plugins folder inside you Eclipse, and then discard the current directory, unzip the original download and replace your plugins with the backup. You are up and running on a new instance, no holds barred !!